# Error when trying to use seasonal_decompose from Statsmodels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

I have the following dataframe called 'data':

| **Month** | Revenue Index |
| --- | --- |
| **1920-01-01** | 1.72 |
| **1920-02-01** | 1.83 |
| **1920-03-01** | 1.94 |
| **...** | ... |
| **2021-10-01** | 114.20 |
| **2021-11-01** | 115.94 |
| **2021-12-01** | 116.01 |

This is essentially a monthly revenue index on which I am trying to use seasonal_decompose with the following code:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(data['Revenue Index'], model='multiplicative')
```

But unfortunately I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-08e3139bbf77> in <module>()
----> 1 result = seasonal_decompose(data['Consumptieprijsindex'], model='multiplicative')
      2 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 6
      3 plt.rc('lines', linewidth=1, color='r')
      4 
      5 fig = result.plot()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/statsmodels/tsa/seasonal.py in seasonal_decompose(x, model, filt, freq, two_sided, extrapolate_trend)
    125             freq = pfreq
    126         else:
--> 127             raise ValueError("You must specify a freq or x must be a "
    128                              "pandas object with a timeseries index with "
    129                              "a freq not set to None")

ValueError: You must specify a freq or x must be a pandas object with a timeseries index with a freq not set to None
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What about doing what the error says :) `seasonal_decompose(data['Revenue Index'], model='multiplicative', period=12)`; 12 is as your data is monthly.

Comment: You can also do `seasonal_decompose(data.set_index("Month")['Revenue Index'], model='multiplicative', period=12)`; this preserves Month information that might be used in the decomposition output.

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-ff5d47d4848f> in <module>()
----> 1 result = seasonal_decompose(data['Consumptieprijsindex'], model='multiplicative', period = 12)
      2 rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 12, 6
      3 plt.rc('lines', linewidth=1, color='r')
      4 
      5 fig = result.plot()

TypeError: seasonal_decompose() got an unexpected keyword argument 'period'

Comment: How do you import `seasonal_decompose`? And can you share what does `import statsmodels.api as sm; print(sm.__version__)` say? The latter says the version of statsmodels you're using.

Comment: Importing it like this: `from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose`
The answer to `statsmodels.api as sm; print(sm.__version__)` is `0.10.2`

Comment: Okay so your version is a bit old. In that case you need `freq=12` instead of `period=12`. As an aside 0.10.2 is kind of old and you might want to upgrade to more recent versions but that's up to you.

Comment: Using a Google Collab environment for testing purposes but planning to deploy it on a server later. Is it possible to import the latest possible version in Google Collab?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But it might be backwards incompatible as we experienced with this post :) You can go to a cell of Colab and type `!pip install statsmodels --upgrade` to upgrade it to the latest version there, i.e., 0.13.1 I believe.

Comment: (Then you might need to restart the environment.)

Comment: Thanks! You answered my question, I wished I could mark your comment but it seems like this is not possible!

Comment: I'm glad it is solved, no problem about marking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in the comments answered my question:

```
result = seasonal_decompose(data['Revenue Index'], model='multiplicative', period=12)
```